# Get header of dataframe if value below threshold else put 'noise'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below:

```
speaker  Scarlett Johanson  Mark Ruffalo  Chris Evans
0                 0.790857      1.044091     0.984198
1                 0.895030      0.672590     1.072131
2                 0.925493      0.078618     0.800736
3                 0.296032      0.550027     0.978062
4                 0.669364      0.499356     0.940024
```

So what I am trying to achieve is if the row wise minimum is greater than a threshold say 0.3 I want value as 'noise' otherwise I want the name of the column as the value.

Eg: 0th Row -> min is 0.7 which is greater than 0.3 so `noise`

2nd Row -> min is 0.07 which is less than 0.3 so  value should be `Mark Ruffalo`.

I am trying to get this in a new column, say `'Final Result'`.

I tried something like this:

```
d['final'] = np.where(d.min(axis=1) >= 0.3, 'noise', 'no_noise')
```

but not understanding how to replace the text `'no_noise'` with column_header. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: `df.idxmin`**:

Find the minimum index using [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html), which returns the index of the first occurrence of minimum over the requested axis

```
# set speaker as index so it's out of the way
df.set_index('speaker', inplace=True)
# set your threshold
thresh = 0.3
# use np.where with `df.idxmin` as the other
df['final'] = np.where(df.min(1) > thresh, 'noise', df.idxmin(1))

>>> df
         Scarlett Johanson  Mark Ruffalo  Chris Evans              final
speaker                                                                 
0                 0.790857      1.044091     0.984198              noise
1                 0.895030      0.672590     1.072131              noise
2                 0.925493      0.078618     0.800736       Mark Ruffalo
3                 0.296032      0.550027     0.978062  Scarlett Johanson
4                 0.669364      0.499356     0.940024              noise
```

**solution 2: `np.argmin`**
You can use [`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to find where the minimum value is found, and index the column names by the result of that in your call to `np.where`:

```
# set speaker as index so it's out of the way
df.set_index('speaker', inplace=True)   
# set your threshold
thresh = 0.3
# use np.where and np.argmin:
df['final'] = np.where(df.min(1) > thresh, 'noise', df.columns[np.argmin(df.values,1)])

>>> df
         Scarlett Johanson  Mark Ruffalo  Chris Evans              final
speaker                                                                 
0                 0.790857      1.044091     0.984198              noise
1                 0.895030      0.672590     1.072131              noise
2                 0.925493      0.078618     0.800736       Mark Ruffalo
3                 0.296032      0.550027     0.978062  Scarlett Johanson
4                 0.669364      0.499356     0.940024              noise
```